# T-SQL: Matching / mapping combinations of values in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've two tables, table1:-

```
ID       Row ID  Value
2447234  1       456
2447234  2       1394
```

and table2

```
ID        Value
2447234   20
2447234   68
2447234   -106
2447234   160
2447234   208
2447234   1500
```

Table1 contains a list of summary totals, and table2 a breakdown of these into smaller parts.  These are both sourced from separate systems with just the ID columns joining as keys

Some combination of the values in table2 will total the values in table1.  See below for an example which details which RowID in table1 maps to the values in table2:-

```
ID         Value    Mapping
2447234   20        1
2447234   68        1
2447234   -106      2
2447234   160       1
2447234   208       1
2447234   1500      2
```

So, as you can see, the total of all values that map to 1 in table2 are equal to the Value column of the associated RowID in table 1.  This mapping is what I would like to achieve.

What would be the best way of achieving this in T-SQL?  I've thought about some kind of cursor or loop but I'm feeling that would be really messy.  The data I've provided is a really simplified subset of larger tables containing multiple IDs and different values that will map in the same way.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: So... let me get this right, you're saying that the value of the sum of certain values in `table2` will create the absolute value of a value in `Table1`? So, for example `106 + -1500 = -1394` - `ABS(-1394) = 1394 = ID2`. Honestly, T-SQL is not the right choice for trying to work this out.

Comment: Apologies, let me alter the question - meant to switch the signs on table1 to simplify.

Comment: i don't understand how you get the values for the Mapping column. The table is identical to table2... with the addition to this column which seems irrelevant

Comment: The Mapping column values come from table1 e.g. the sum of Values in table2.Mappping = 1 is the same as the Value column with RowID = 1 in table1.

Comment: You would havce to check somehow all combinations, which even with small table would be very complex.

Comment: Yep - I figured this, just wondering if there was a simple / elegant way of doing it before I come up with something messy!

Comment: You might also have multiple solutions depending on the data.

Comment: You must be aware of how complex it is. The amount of possible sums to check is 2^n, so using your example, you have 6 rows which gives 64 sums, which is alright. But when you have 10, the number of sums is 1024, and it grows exponentially.

Comment: I know this...and I really do know how complex it is too.  This is why I thought I'd ask in case there was some simple way of doing it, because I couldn't think of anything that wasn't a complete nightmare to manage.  Main point is whichever way I choose I have to figure out how to do it...

Comment: What if you have multiple possible combinations of rows in table2 that all sums up to the same value in table1? How will you choose which one is correct?

Comment: You might want to head back and check what is the process in getting those data into the tables, there should be at least a table that shows you the mapping like the 3rd table u have provided. There are just too many combinations/solutions that could give you

Answer (score 0):

Uh, oh, this is only for 2 values.
This will miss on duplicate value but you don't have a row identifier in table2.

```
select t1.*, t2a.value, t2b.value 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2a 
  on t2a.id = t1.id 
join table2 t2b 
  on t2b.id = t1.id  
 and t2b.value > t2a.value 
 and t2b.value + t2a.value = t1.value 
order by t1.id, tta.value, t2b.value
```

This is not perfect but hopefully it is a start:

```
declare @t1 table (id int, rowId int, value int);
insert into @t1 values
       (2447234, 1, 456)
     , (2447234, 2, 1394);
declare @t2 table (iden int identity primary key, id int, value int);  
insert into @t2 (id, value) values
       (2447234,   20)
     , (2447234,   68)
     , (2447234,   -106)
     , (2447234,   160)
     , (2447234,   208)
     , (2447234,   1500);
--select * from @t1;
--select * from @t2;
with cte as 
( select t1.id, t1.rowId, t1.value as value1, t2.value as value2, t2.value as ssum , iter = 1, t2.iden as origIden, t2.iden 
    from @t1 t1 
    join @t2 t2 
      on t2.id = t1.id 
  union all 
  select t1.id, t1.rowId, t1.value1          , t2.value         , t1.ssum + t2.value, iter + 1, t1.origIden        , t2.iden 
    from cte t1 
    join @t2 t2 
      on t2.id = t1.id 
     and t2.iden > t1.iden  
   where t1.ssum + t2.value <= t1.value1
)
select * from cte
order by rowID, id, origIden, iter
```